# MS Lightswitch - How to set TimeOut for connection

Tags: c#, silverlight, iis, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am using Microsoft Lightswitch with Silverlight client. I am facing timeout error after 30 seconds. I am unable to change this. I tried to change in web.config but it makes no effect. And within C# screens code, there is also no way to change this in DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.

Is there any way to change timeout for lightswitch applications. Application is hosted in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to double click properties in the desktop client solution.

Click screen navigation.

Click the "Click here to view application code" link.

Application_Initialize partial method, add the following line of code:

this.Details.ClientTimeout = 100000;

This will extend you connection timeout to 100 second.

Comment: Yes @pualpitchford, tried this code also, but still getting timeout error after 30 seconds.

Comment: That's strange it worked for me one time. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="DataSourceName_CommandTimeout" value="60" />
</appSettings>
```

worked for me.
from here : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4b6f5571-a594-434c-8302-677a272bb930/set-connection-timeout-in-lightswitch-html?forum=lightswitch